# How to use pigeonhole principle to prove result about odd primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $n$ and $k$ are positive integers with $n>1$ and all $n$ positive integers $a, a+k, ..., a+(n-1)k$ are odd primes, then $k$ is divisible by every prime less then $n$.

*My solution:*

$a=p*q_0+r_0$

$a+k=p*q_1+r_1$

...

$a+(n-1)k=p*q_{n-1}+r_{n-1}$

**How can I apply the pigeonhole principle to my solution? 
The textbook solution is not similar to my solution...**

[image]

Comment: Can you please stop posting your question as picture, and learn to format mathematics on this website : [using MathJax (follow this hyperlink)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You applied divisibility with reminder to all $n$ positive integers ... the text book applies it to the fist $p+1$ only. Your solution may not work if, say, 1st and the last of positive integers have the same reminder, which means $p \mid (n-1)k$. Since $n-1\geq p$, $p$ may still divide $n-1$ which brings some difficulties to proving $p \mid k$. I'd say, stick with the book.